# Numbers of elements of order $p$ in $Sym(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

First of all, I saw that question [Number of Elements of order $p$ in $S_{p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/number-of-elements-of-order-p-in-s-p) and additionally ask this question. Please inform me if there is such question in the site then we can close question.

Numbers of elements of order $p$ in $Sym(n)$ where $Sym(n)$ denotes symetric group of order $n!$ .

I thought it is better to start with $p$-cycles as their order is $p$. And order is depends on $n$ and $p$ so we should divide in a cases.

Any comments, suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is $p$ prime? ${}$

Comment: Sorry to dont mention. Yes $p$ is prime.

Comment: I'm sorry I closed the question.  It wasn't a duplicate after all.

Comment: According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1704703/104041), it's $${n\choose p}(p-1)! +\sum_{k=2}^{[\frac{n}{p}]} \frac{n!}{k!p^k}.$$

Comment: The general case, i.e., how many elements of order $k$ in $S_n$, is discussed in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-particular-order-in-the-symmetric-group).

Answer (score 1):

If the OP meant $p$ is prime then $S_n$ acts by conjugation on the elements of order $p$.

The orbits are the $o_k,k\le n/p$ where $o_k$ is the set of elements with $k$ ($p$-cycles) and $n-kp$ ($1$-cycles).

The stabilizer of an element of $o_k$ has $(n-kp)! p^k k!$ elements.

So $o_k$ contains $\frac{n!}{(n-kp)! p^k k!}$ elements and there are $$\sum_{k=1}^{n/p} \frac{n!}{(n-kp)! p^k k!}$$ elements of order $p$.